# Do chess coaches ever get disappointed with their students?

Tags: coach

I'm wondering if a student can disappoint their chess coach if they lose to many games for a long duration of time or any other reasons. What have been your experience as a student or teacher?

Comment: Yes, coaches can become disappointed, as well as feel the full spectrum of human emotions.

Answer (score 2):

I, as a teacher of elementary age students, don't get disappointed in the students' results.  I only get disappointed if the student doesn't try.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a Chess Coach though but surely a coach will get disappointed if the student commits the same mistake over a period of time, and does not show discipline enough to improve his weaknesses.

A coach will get disappointed if a student is unworthy to take any lessons and does not show interest in chess.

A coach may get disappointed if a brilliant student is unable to pay his fees on time.

As students are a reflection of their teacher's training, and learning, a coach will want his students to shine so that his name also shines along with them.

There can be other different cases but the above ones are most common.

Comment: I disagree with all your points.

#1: That is a coaching problem, not a student problem
#2: Why are you teaching students who don't want to learn the game?
#3: Then, you are doing it for the money, and not for the art.
#4: This is pride.

Comment: @Priyome In the real world, not all coaches and students are ideal.  Maybe a student not learning is a coaching problem and maybe not, but even if it objectively is a coaching problem, that doesn't mean the coach thinks so.  Maybe a student is there because their parents make them.  And maybe a coach really needs the money.

Comment: Oh come on @Priyome ..please do not get emotional . Tell me something in this world where money is not involved . I agree some People will surely teach Chess not for the sake of money but for the love & sanctification of the Game but I said that Money may be one of the reason .

Comment: I think your answers are not in the spirit of the question. Seems he is asking what "chess-related" reasons might a coach become disappointed. You gave him answers that have little to do with actual chess and the promotion of a student's talent. Sorry you could not understand that. In that, I am disappointed.